# Magento2 - Get Region JSON

Tags: magento2

The following `Magento1` code gets me a `JSON` string of all country regions (`states, provinces, cantons`, etc.)

`Mage::helper('directory')->getRegionJson()`

What is the equivalent code in `Magento2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

`$this->get('\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data')->getRegionJson()`